# Pygame Subset for Android not finding javac

Tags: java, android, python, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install Pygame Subset for Android on my Linux machine, using Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed java and added it the the PATH, so I can type `javac -version` and get the version, verifying that it is installed (it is `javac 1.7.0_79` for reference). However, running the PGS4A script `./android.py installsdk` gives a long list of errors ending in `Without a working JDK, I can't continue`. But I have installed the jdk, I am even able to compile the test program test.java in the PGS4A directory. Why doesn't this work?